# php cgi error in PhpStorm when php-cgi is installed

Tags: php, cgi, phpstorm, fastcgi

I am having a problem with PhpStorm (10.0.3) on OS X El Capitan‎ throwing a php-cgi not found error on PHP 7 cgi/fastcgi.  I tried the solutions offered in "[How do I install php-cgi? I tried MacPort, Package and everything else but none works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406844/how-do-i-install-php-cgi-i-tried-macport-package-and-everything-else-but-none)", but these did not work. I've consulted this: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/09/built-in-webserver-in-phpstorm/ but it is not helpful. I also tried a cgi install of PHP 5.6 but this has the same problem as PHP 7.

I have installed PHP70-cgi using macport and verified the install is cgi-fcgi:

```
$ php-cgi70 -v
PHP 7.0.2 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jan 19 2016 16:48:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

When I try to use php-cgi70 from within PhpStorm it appears to incorrectly default to CLI:

```
PHP version: 7.0.2
PHP CLI: /opt/local/bin/php-cgi70 PHP CGI: Not Installed (php-cgi sapi is necessary to use built-in web server) 
Loaded Configuration File: /opt/local/etc/php70/php.ini
```

I've also tried the macport install of php-fpm70, but this is not recognized by PhpStorm.

Does anyone have any ideas on resolving this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm can't find the PHP CGI binary. Do this on your shell to fix:

```
cd /opt/local/bin
sudo ln -s php-cgi70 php-cgi
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install php-xdebug

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16075043)

Comment: @georoot There is no link in this answer. Please don't just add random review comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way for macOS is to install PHP all together with simple cURL:**

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.2
```

**OR install Homebrew and then PHP with CGI (better practice):**

1. `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. `brew install php72 --with-cgi --with-debug --with-libmysql`

**And link it in PhpStorm:**

Image: [PhpStorm: PHP Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm0LL.png)

---

For more info about Homebrew, visit documentation [here](https://brew.sh).