# php-cgi not found in PhpStorm resulting in 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, macos, phpstorm, cgi

I'm trying to run a simple php file with PhpStorm (v2017.3). It should output a `var_dump`, but I constantly encounter a 502 bad gateway error in my browser when running the script. I receive the following error in the PhpStorm:

> php-cgi not found: Please ensure that configured PHP Interpreter built as CGI program (--enable-fastcgi was specified)

When I run `php -v` in my terminal here is the output:

```
PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Here are the things I've tried so far:

- Reinstalling PHP with homebrew with `brew uninstall php71` and then `brew install71`.
- Adding the `--with-cgi` option to my `brew install php71` command
- Read through the following threads: [phpStorm problems with php-cgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239128/phpstorm-problems-with-php-cgi), [php cgi error in PhpStorm when php-cgi is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892046/php-cgi-error-in-phpstorm-when-php-cgi-is-installed)

Comment: so, did you set phpStorm's php interpreter to point to `/usr/local/bin/php` ? Prefs, Languages & Frameworks, PHP -> CLI interpreter. Click on the '...' and point to the php in /usr/local/bin

Comment: @YvesLeBorg The PhpStorm's interpreter is pointing to `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: You're a life savor @YvesLeBorg! It worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Homebrew typically installs the binaries in the `/usr/local/bin` folder. To finalize this installation, you should tell PhpStorm which interpreter it is using. If you dont do the following step, PhpStorm will autodetect the php shipped with OSX.

Open preferences, go to `Languages & Frameworks`, select PHP, and you will see the appropriate settings. For the PHP Ececutable, there is a **`...`**, click on it and you will see :

[image: preferences]

Just navigate to `/usr/local/bin` and click on the php binary, the one from homebrew.

ps : the 'ini' files you need to edit are in `/usr/local/etc/php/M.m` where M.m are major.minor version of the installed php (7.1 in your case).

Answer (score 23):

I had this same issue. I have the php installed but I need the CGI module. For Ubuntu users it is easy, just run this command:

```sh
sudo apt install -y php7.2-cgi
```

This command will install the stable version of php that is 7.2. You can install the version 7.1, 5.5, or what ever you need.

For Mac user you can install using this script:

```sh
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.2
```

Check [this link](https://php-osx.liip.ch/) or read [the php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.php) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

These are the steps to solve this common issue:

1. Setup Brew: `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Update Brew: `brew update`
3. Add repo: `brew tap homebrew/php`
4. Install PHP: `brew install php`

   - Go to PhpStorm `Preferences` menu follow the `Languages & Frameworks` and then go to `PHP` section
   - In this section click `...` button next to `CLI Interpreter` setting
   - In Pop-up menu click `+` and then choose `Other Local...` ,  enter this address `/usr/local/bin/php` to the `PHP executable:` section in menu
   - Now, you are done! Click Apply and Save.

Comment: (Addition 2019) After step 1. you should do: `brew analytics off`.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error using PHPStorm with MAMP, so in this case I configure the PHPStorm to using php-cgi installed by MAMP.
For this in PHPStorm, open `Preferences` —> `Languages` —> `PHP` and configure like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

install php-cgi for Mac and Linux os

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).